# FadeIn and FadaOut in same moment while animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity, fadein, fadeout

```
$(".item21").click((function() {

    var i = 0;
    return function() {
        $("#submenu").animate({
            marginTop: (++i % 2) ? "+=330px" : "-=330px"
            }, 400);
            return false;
        };
    })());
```

Where and what can I add so that script will made #submenu fading in or fading out on every second click. I tried something with opacity:0 but I'm stuck.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick: [jQuery Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

`$('#submenu').toggle();`

Comment: You won't be able to click something that is display:none

Comment: I am assuming that the item is apart of the submenu, but that could be wrong.

Comment: Grrrrrrr I hate when I start in one way and must finish in other :)
I made this and now it's working. Thanks

    $(".item21").toggle(
      function () {
        $("#submenu").animate({
    marginTop: "+=330px",
    opacity:1
    }, 400);
      },
      function () {
        $("#submenu").animate({
    marginTop: "-=330px",
    opacity:0
    }, 400);
      }
    );

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut)?

Comment: can you click on something that has been faded out?

Comment: I guess I thought they were separate elements because he used different selectors to identify them in the code sample.

Comment: yeah... kinda hard to tell without the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.css({ visibility: value })` instead of opacity.